# Access save query externally to run on other computers?

Tags: sql, vba, batch-file, ms-access

I have a mdb file that needs to be fixed.
I don't have the latest copy, as it is still in use. I have an older back up which I created an sql query. 

Is there a way I can save the query externally? Or create a single file that will run the query without people needing to go into Microsoft access?

Comment: In short, the answer is that you can store an sql query anywhere, effectively just a text string, so  save it to a .txt file, and you can reuse it.  If you want to query the db from a spreadsheet, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842607/how-to-query-a-ms-access-table-from-ms-excel-2010-using-vba

Comment: MS Access is like any other database and so most language/programs (Java, C#, Python, PHP, Perl, Excel, R, Stata, SAS, VB) can connect to it via ODBC and run SQL queries without ever opening up the MSAccess.exe GUI program. In fact, PC users don't need this Office app installed.