# Excel VBA with Application.ScreenUpdating does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in excel VBA which runs other macros. I am trying to implement Application.Screenupdating so that the user does not get to see what the macros do. However it seems to work for every macro, other than AccImport which is the main macro that I do not want my user to be aware of.

This macro does a spreadsheet transfer from excel to access, and I do not want my users to be aware of my access database. Within this macro it does a spreadsheet transfer by opening the access database, then closing it. Below is the main macro that I trigger, screenupdating=false seems to work for all the macros other than AccImport.

Any ideas? Thank you.

```
Sub ENTER1Dim2()


'
' ENTER1 Macro
'

'
If Worksheets("DIM21").Range("AR32") = 0 Then
MsgBox "Please enter DATA completely first"
End
Else

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Run "'NEW.xlsm'!TransferE1Dim2"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Run "'NEW.xlsm'!PWDOFF"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Run "'NEW.xlsm'!ProtectE1Dim2"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Run "'NEW.xlsm'!UnprotectE2Dim2"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Run "'NEW.xlsm'!ClearE2Dim2"

Sheets("Data1").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Run "'NEW.xlsm'!AccImport"

Sheets("DIM21").Select
Range("G41").Select

Application.Run "'NEW.xlsm'!PWDON"
Call AUTOSAVE
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Macro below is AccImport.

```
Sub AccImport()




'Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01"), "AccImport"

Dim Acc As New Access.Application
Acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\yilmadu001\Desktop\Database.accdb"

Acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        TableName:="Table1", _
        Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        HasFieldNames:=True, _
        Range:="Data1$A1:BL40000"
Acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
Acc.Quit
Set Acc = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: Note that ScreenUpdating is limited to the Excel Application class, and (I think) only to the specific instance of Excel under the current thread. If you're creating a new Excel object, or if you're opening an Access Database or some other application, ScreenUpdating=False will not prevent that from displaying to the user.

Comment: @DavidZemens I have included it, it is by creating an excel object. Is screenupdating impossible if we create an object?

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Don't open Access. Use ADO instead.

Comment: try adding `Acc.visible = false` to the `AccImport` sub. This will stop access from being visible. However, ado would probably better way to go

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I'm not entirely clear on why it isn't false.  The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-visible-property-access) says that "When an Application object is created by using Automation, the Visible and UserControl properties of the object are both set to False." I almost wonder if it's a side effect of the `OpenCurrentDatabase` call.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman that did not work, I guess I will try to come up with an ADO script, I am just not too familiar with it

Comment: @DYilm - conceptually, you'll build sql to insert the data from excel into the table. So it will be different than direct `transferSpreadsheet` available in access.

Comment: why not read the DB tables [using ADO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842607/how-to-query-a-ms-access-table-from-ms-excel-2010-using-vba)

Comment: [Microsoft Access: Use ADO to Execute SQL statements](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=172:microsoft-access-use-ado-to-execute-sql-statements&catid=79&Itemid=475)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I must run the code from excel, is this possible with ADO? or does it have to be run from Access

Comment: @DYilm - yes, it's possible with ADO. you can reference ADO in Excel and then write SQL to your hearts content. it's not very difficult at all and there's plenty of help online to learn how to set it up